# Estimating derivatives with randomness

Tags: probability, derivatives, expectation

Assume $Y$ is a continuously differential function of $X$. Given i.i.d. data $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^n$, I would like to estimate $E\left[g\left(\left.\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}\right|_{X=X_0}\right)\right]$ for some known nonlinear function $g$ ($g$ can be assumed continuously differential, if needed, for example $g(x)=x^2$).

This question is an extension of [Estimating the expectation of a derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421825/estimating-the-expectation-of-a-derivative) where $g$ was linear and the derivative and integral could be exchanged and kernel techniques used.

I am interested to know how the expectation can be estimated when $g$ is nonlinear and the integral and derivative cannot be exchanged. The underlying motivation for the question is estimation of $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}$ when there is randomness.

My idea was to do something similar to kernel estimation by giving weights to points around $X_0$ based on how close they are to $X_0$ and then sample two points at a time based on the weights, say $(y_i,x_i)$ and $(y_j,x_j)$, and calculate $g(\frac{y_i-y_j}{x_i-x_j})$ and do this many times and take the sample average.

Answer (score 1):

The Derivative, is a **point-wise** property in general case.

When talking about a linear regression $y=mx+n$, obviously, the derivative is the same throughout the sample $y'=m$. (i.e. the [slope](http://www.mathplanet.com/education/pre-algebra/graphing-and-functions/the-slope-of-a-linear-function))

However, in the general case you need to take one of two approaches:

## Have a prior

If you know your data is going to behave in a certain way, use your assumptions as a model.

For example,
 if you assume that $y=ax^2+bx+c$,
 then our model parameters are $a$,$b$ and $c$.

fit your data to this model using [Maximum-likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) or [Bayesian inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_statistics) and the derivative will be $y'=2a_*x+b_*$  where $(a_*,b_*,c_*)$ are your best fit.

## Local linearity

[Spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) techniques are the best practice for modelling general functions.

Splines are (very roughly speaking) dividing your data into segments, and modelling each of them separately, and stitching the models together in to a continuous function.

For example, In your case you could assume that $0<x_i<1$ behave linearly as $y_1=a_1x+b_1$, and $1<x<2$ behave as $y_2=a_2x+b_2$.

The common practice is to use linear,quadratic, or cubic splines, depending on the properties you want the functions to have on the "stitch points".

I would suggest modelling a general function as linear approximation of a [moving window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average), and the derivative at each point would be the slope corresponding to each window.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I was hoping for something even more general i.e. $y=f(x,\varepsilon)$ so that the derivative is random.

Comment: Using bayesian inference, you have the distribution of the coefficients, and thus the distribution of the derivative, like any other random variable

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. It's not exactly what I had in mind because potentially the derivative can be (pointwise) random (and I don't see how the coefficients can be random in your setup) so I give you the 50 points but wait to see if perhaps there is a better answer.